# Bartender error: 'Web Service' requires the 'Enterprise Automation' edition or better to run

Tags: bartender

I am trying to add a web service following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BzwxVt894Zg). However, when I try to test the web service, pressing `Start` I am getting the above error:

> Web Service Integration' requires the 'Enterprise Automation' edition
>   or better to run.

BarTender version that I have is:

```
Program:    BarTender Designer 2016 R8
License:    Automation (3 Printers)
Version:    11.0.8.3153 (64-bit)
OS: Windows 10 Pro x64 build 18362
```

I also tried `Enterprise Automation` edition (DEMO version) but I am getting the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same error. BarTender's support team gave the following answer:

> In BarTender v2016 Web Service integrations are only available in Enterprise Automation edition. If you have an active maintenance contract, so you could consider planning your upgrade to v2019.
>
> Find the recommended steps to upgrade to v2019:
>   [Updating to BarTender 2019](https://support.seagullscientific.com/hc/en-us/articles/360020811153-Updating-to-BarTender-2019?source=search&auth_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJhY2NvdW50X2lkIjo3MTE0MzQsInVzZXJfaWQiOjM5NzcxMTc0MTQzMywidGlja2V0X2lkIjoyNDE2NjUsImNoYW5uZWxfaWQiOjYzLCJ0eXBlIjoiU0VBUkNIIiwiZXhwIjoxNTc3MjgxODk1fQ.1TU77gCRzkUM9B7Zh_26nLRlsItUhcOWTd3QJggx0Bw)
>
> Do note that the licensing system in v2019 is not backwards compatible, therefore, we do recommend you that you test v2019 first using the provisional activation.

Comment: Indeed. I downloaded the v2019 and the web service run without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue, so I used ActiveX instead and it works.
My back end is running on python. See code attached. You can also convert it to work with different programming languages.

```
import win32com.client as win32

btApp = win32.Dispatch("BarTender.Application")
btApp.Visible = True


btFormat = btApp.Formats.Open("C:\\Users\\someUser\\Desktop\\YourLabel.btw", False, "PrinterName")

btFormat.SetNamedSubStringValue("btField1", "Data1")
btFormat.SetNamedSubStringValue("btField2", "Data2")
btFormat.SetNamedSubStringValue("btField3", "Data3")

btFormat.IdenticalCopiesOfLabel = 1
btFormat.PrintOut(False, False)
btFormat.Close(1)
btApp.Quit(1)
```